Set max bounds for tiled layers with different resolutions in Leaflet
I'm trying to create a map with raster images using Leaflet's TileLayer and CRS.Simple projection. I want to be able to switch between two images with different resolutions:

Image one: 5120 x 3840
Image two: 2560 x 1920

I used gdal2tiles to create tiles out of those images with zoom levels 2-7.
I extended the CRS projection to flip the y axis:
const CRSPixel = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
  transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 0, 1, 0),
});

Where I'm completely lost is when setting the map boundaries, so the user cannot drag outside of the map. I'm using the following approach:
const southWest = map.unproject([0, image.height], image.nativeZoom);
const northEast = map.unproject([image.width, 0], image.nativeZoom);

const bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

What I can't wrap my head around is the 2nd argument of the map.unproject's method (in my case image.nativeZoom) and why it's 5 for the 1st image and 4 for the 2nd image to obtain the correct boundaries. I initially thought it's supposed to be the maxZoom, which is 7 for both tileLayers, but that value totally messes up the boundaries for both.
What is that number, why is it different for both layers and how to compute it?
I created the following fiddle to demonstrate the issue. The "zoom" value sent to map.unproject to compute the bounds is stored in nativeZoom property. I also created two markers at the southWest and northEast coordinates which you can see when you fully unzoom the map:
https://jsfiddle.net/matejm/aqbex679/latest

Cross posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79178922/leaflet-setmaxbounds-for-images-with-different-resolutions

Leaflet docs for map.unproject method say that it's inverse of map.project method, which is described as:

Projects a geographical coordinate LatLng according to the projection
of the map's CRS, then scales it according to zoom and the CRS's
Transformation. The result is pixel coordinate relative to the CRS
origin.

For each image you have to find zoom level where tiles cover the whole image at image resolution, which means one pixel in tile corresponds to one pixel in image.
One raster layer tile of size 256 x 256 pixels covers the whole CRS extent at zoom 0. On zoom 1 there are 4 such tiles, covering area of 512 x 512 pixels ans so on. On zoom 4 there are 32 tiles covering area of 4096 x 4096 pixels. On zoom 5 there are 64 tiles covering area of 8192 x 8192 pixels.
Image one has size of 5120 x 3840 pixels, so tiles cover the whole image at zoom 5 at pictures's native size, where 1 pixel in tile corresponds to 1 pixel in image.
Image two has size of 2560 x 1920 pixels, so tiles cover the whole image at zoom 4 at pictures's native size, where 1 pixel in tile corresponds to 1 pixel in image.
